# 7 segments display with arduino mega2560

Tags: arduino

I doing a small project with 6 display 7 segment (I will call A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, A6) and 3 cd4543B (I will call Da, Db, Dc) with an arduino mega 2560. I also use 3 transistor

Da is use for A1, A2

Db is use for A3, A4

Dc is use for A5, A6

The circuit is done, and work if I use only 4 display I have tried different combination (A1, A2, A3, A4, or A1, A2, A5, A6 or A2, A3, A4, A5, or A3, A4, A5, A6) and all work well.

but If I want to use five or six display, nothing work....

I don't understand why it's not working, I'm using the same method than for 4 display.

Is there specificity with arduino mega2560 ?

my code for 5 display:

```
//Da
const int bit_A=8;
const int bit_B=9;
const int bit_C=10;
const int bit_D=11;
//Db
const int bit_E=22;
const int bit_F=24;
const int bit_G=26;
const int bit_H=28;
//Dc
const int bit_I=40;
const int bit_J=42;
const int bit_K=44;
const int bit_L=46;

// transistors
const int alim_dizainemillier= 3;
const int alim_millier=4;
const int alim_centaine=5;
const int alim_dizaine=6;
const int alim_unite=7;

void setup()
{

pinMode(bit_A,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_B,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_C,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_D,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_E,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_F,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_G,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_H,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_I,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_J,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_K,OUTPUT);
pinMode(bit_L,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_dizainemillier,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_millier,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_centaine,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_dizaine,OUTPUT);
pinMode(alim_unite,OUTPUT);

digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);  
}

void loop() 
{
 for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
 {
   afficher_nombre(i);

 }
}




void afficher_nombre(int nombre)

{
 long temps;
 int unite=0,dizaine=0,centaine=0, millier=0, dizainemillier=0;
 dizainemillier=nombre/10000;
 millier=(nombre-(10000*dizainemillier))/1000;
 centaine=(nombre-1000*millier)-(10000+dizainemillier)/100;
 dizaine=(nombre-(centaine*100)-(millier*1000)-(dizainemillier*10000))/10;
 unite=nombre-(dizainemillier*10000)-(millier*1000)-(centaine*100)-(dizaine*10);

 temps=millis();
 while((millis()-temps)<500){   



    digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,HIGH);
    afficher_CD(dizainemillier);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
    delay(5);


 https://www.arduino.cc/   digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_millier,HIGH);
    afficher_CM(millier);
    digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
    digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
    delay(5);


   digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_centaine,HIGH);
   afficher_CM(centaine);
   digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
  digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
   delay(5);


   digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,HIGH);
   afficher_UD(dizaine);
   digitalWrite(alim_unite,LOW);
   delay(5);

   digitalWrite(alim_dizainemillier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_millier,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_centaine,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_dizaine,LOW);
   digitalWrite(alim_unite,HIGH);
   afficher_UD(unite);
   delay(5);
 }
}


void afficher_UD(int chiffre)
{
  digitalWrite(bit_A,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_B,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_C,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_D,LOW);

      if(chiffre>=8)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_D,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-8;
         }
     if(chiffre>=4)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_C,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-4;
         }
    if(chiffre>=2)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_B,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-2;
         }
    if(chiffre>=1)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_A,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-1;
         }
}


void afficher_CM(int chiffre)
{
  digitalWrite(bit_E,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_F,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_G,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_H,LOW);

      if(chiffre>=8)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_H,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-8;
         }
     if(chiffre>=4)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_G,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-4;
         }
    if(chiffre>=2)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_F,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-2;
         }
    if(chiffre>=1)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_E,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-1;
         }
}

void afficher_CD(int chiffre)
{
  digitalWrite(bit_I,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_J,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_K,LOW);
  digitalWrite(bit_L,LOW);

      if(chiffre>=8)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_L,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-8;
         }
     if(chiffre>=4)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_K,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-4;
         }
    if(chiffre>=2)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_J,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-2;
         }
    if(chiffre>=1)
         {
           digitalWrite(bit_I,HIGH);
           chiffre=chiffre-1;
         }
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a problem of bits ... :

arduino work in 16 bits so to count up to 100000 need to use a `long` :

```
...
void loop() 
{
 for(long i=0;i<10000;i++)
 {
   afficher_nombre(i);

 }
}

void afficher_nombre(long nombre)
....
```